# gRPC: What is the recommended way to shut down an asynchronous server in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, server, grpc, shutdown

I have a gRPC server that hosts two asynchronous services ("Master" and "Worker"), and I would like to implement graceful shutdown for the server. Each service has its own `grpc::CompletionQueue`.

There appear to be two `Shutdown()` methods that might be relevant: [`grpc::CompletionQueue::Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a40efddadd9073386fbcb4f46e8325670) and [`grpc::Server::Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server.html#a777a9c8873ae4969585083e0e62482dc), but it's not clear from the documentation which ones should be used.

What is a good pattern for shutting down an asynchronous service?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You must call both [`grpc::Server::Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server.html#a777a9c8873ae4969585083e0e62482dc) and [`grpc::CompletionQueue::Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a40efddadd9073386fbcb4f46e8325670) (for each completion queue used in the service) to shut down cleanly.

1. If you call [`cq_->Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a40efddadd9073386fbcb4f46e8325670), the only observable effect is that subsequent calls to `Service::AsyncService::RequestFoo()` (the generated method for the corresponding `Foo` RPC) fail with an assertion. From reading the documentation of the corresponding C API method ([`grpc_completion_queue_shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/core/grpc_8h.html#a4051b4036c5132f02064430f67420ecd)), it appears that it is illegal to add new work to the queue—i.e. by calling `RequestFoo()`—so I added an `is_shutdown_` member to my service wrapper classes (protected by a mutex) so that no enqueue attempts are made after `cq_->Shutdown()` is called. However, after doing this, the completion queue blocks indefinitely in [`cq_->Next()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a86d9810ced694e50f7987ac90b9f8c1a). None of the enqueued tags complete (with an error or otherwise).
2. If instead you call [`server_->Shutdown()`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server.html#a777a9c8873ae4969585083e0e62482dc), all of the enqueued tags complete immediately (with `ok == false`). However, the completion queue continues to block indefinitely in `cq_->Next()`.

Calling both `cq_->Shutdown()` (for each defined completion queue) and `server_->Shutdown()` results in a clean shutdown.

One caveat: if you use `grpc::ServerContext::AsyncNotifyWhenDone()` to register a tag for call cancellation, these will *not* be returned by `cq_->Next()` if the server shuts down before the initial request is received for that call. You will need to be cautious with the memory management of the corresponding tag structure, if you want to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Great self-answer! A couple of notes. First: According to [the tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html#shutting-down-the-server), the server must be shutdown *before* the completion queue (or queues).

Comment: Second: The fact that `AsyncNotifyWhenDone()` does not get returned by `cq_->Next()` is probably what is mean in [the docs for `Next()`](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a86d9810ced694e50f7987ac90b9f8c1a) when it says, cryptically, "AsyncNotifyWhenDone: ok should always be true". It also says that for client-side finish, so presumably tags for that are also not returned during shutdown.

Comment: Should i preliminary send Finish for all the pending connections? Or it is not required