# gRPC assertion failed when stopping async helloworld server

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, grpc, grpc-c++

I'm trying to shutdown properly a gRPC server.
I use the provided async helloworld from gRPC source.
The file is here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc

I have edited the main like the following:

```cpp
#include "greeter_async_server.cc"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void stop_task(ServerImpl* server) {
    int delay = 10000;
    std::cout << "Server will stop after " << delay / 1000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
    std::cout << "Wait finished" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stoping server..." << std::endl;
    server->Shutdown();
    std::cout << "Stop sent" << std::endl;
}

void server_task(ServerImpl* server) {
    server->Run();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ServerImpl server;

    std::thread server_thread(server_task, &server);
    std::thread stop_thread(stop_task, &server);

    stop_thread.join();
    server_thread.join();
    std::cout << "Server stopped" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
void ServerImpl::Shutdown()
{
    server->Shutdown();
    // Always shutdown the completion queue after the server.
    cq->Shutdown();
}
```

```sh
Server will stop after 10 seconds
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
Wait finished
Stoping server...
E0825 15:08:30.182000000 34960 greeter_async_server.cc:156] assertion failed: ok

Sortie de TestGreeterAsyncServer.exe (processus 37008). Code : -1073740791.
Appuyez sur une touche pour fermer cette fenêtre. . .
```

I don't understand why the server crashes on assertion failed.
The assertion is at line 156:

```cpp
GPR_ASSERT(ok);
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to delete an object (`server`) that's been created on the stack.

---

That said, the example code does not showcase any way to cleanly stop the server once it's been started. It is even said in [a comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc#L51) above the `Run()` method:

> There is no shutdown handling in this code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708348/grpc-what-is-the-recommended-way-to-shut-down-an-asynchronous-server-in-c)  provides good pointers on how to accomplish your goal.

---

Here is why the assertion is triggered:

`cq_->Next(&tag, &ok);` is a blocking call, until either

- An error occurs (which means `ok == false`) ;
- A task is about to be processed (which means `ok == true`) ;
- `cq_->Shutdown()` has been called (which also means `ok == false`).

You can read about all the different scenarios in [`CompletionQueue::Next()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a86d9810ced694e50f7987ac90b9f8c1a) documentation. Since you're shutting down, `ok` is `false` which triggers the assertion's failure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for the stack... You're right. I've been on this problem for too long...

I get the idea but I can't get it to work, yet. I'll look for examples on the web.

Comment: I've edited the code without the delete on the stack.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the solution. thanks again! I'll post the code tomorow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
I have edited the greeter_async_server.cc like this:

```cpp
private:
    // Adding attrbutes
    bool is_shutting_down = false;
    std::mutex mutex;

    void HandleRpcs() {
        new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
        void* tag;
        bool ok;
        while (true) {
            GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
            // Here, added exit condition
            mutex.lock();
            if (true == is_shutting_down) {
                mutex.unlock();
                std::cout << "stop reading" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else mutex.unlock();
            GPR_ASSERT(ok);
            static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
        }
    }

public:
    // Adding Shutdown public method
    void Shutdown() {
        mutex.lock();
        is_shutting_down = true;
        mutex.unlock();

        const std::chrono::milliseconds WaitDuration = std::chrono::milliseconds(50);
        const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> Deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + WaitDuration;

        server_->Shutdown(Deadline);
        cq_->Shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: You can compltely remove the use of the mutex by using an [`std::atomic_bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead of a regular boolean :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll do that ;)